# nodejs/ express sometimes not working

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running nodejs & express on a centos server. and I made the code below which worked fine when I made it... now its giving error ( I haven't even touch it).

the strange thing is if I delete all the lines and add them again one by one it works again; but what I don't understand is that why it ever stops working ?

My Code :

App.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
passport = require('passport-local'),
config = require('./config/config.json');
//CONNECT TO DATABASE - i removed the pass & username when posting
mongo.connect("mongodb://{username}:{pass}@ds037617.mongolab.com:37617/{db}", function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
        throw err;
        } else {
            console.log("successfully connected to the database");
        }
        db.close();
    });
    var publicUser = require('./routes/publicUser'),
    storeUser = require('./routes/publicUser'),
    adminUser = require('./routes/publicUser');
    app = express();
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use('/', publicUser);
    app.use('/store', storeUser);
    app.use('/adminO', adminUser);
    //Load Statics
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('listening.........................................');
    });
```

terminal response/error:

```
30 Apr 18:23:00 - [nodemon] v1.3.7
30 Apr 18:23:00 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
30 Apr 18:23:00 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
30 Apr 18:23:00 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1129:19)
    at listen (net.js:1172:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1257:5)
    at EventEmitter.app.listen (/home/ash/www/recruit/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:595:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ash/www/recruit/app.js:28:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
30 Apr 18:23:01 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: thanks for negative points, but I would appreciate it more if you could explain why

Comment: Be more specific on what you were trying to achieve. State why you think it isn't working. Format your code snippet properly. Follow these pointers and the question might get saved.

Comment: What error is it returning?

Comment: i edited my question, you should now see the error i am getting in terminal. ( no idea if that's even the right place to look for errors.)

Comment: `EACCES` means your permissions are messed up.

Comment: Attempting to listen at port 80 may fail without administration privilege. Try another port greater than 1023, like 8080.

Comment: I am going to have to try this same solution but for osx.

Answer (score 5):

So apparently if the application is configured to listen to any port less than 1024, there is a chance that the server is blocking it and for node to throw error. you can spot this when "Error: listen EACCES" is showing in the terminal.

to fix this I followed the tutorial in [here](http://proghowto.com/iptables-redirect-port-80-to-port-8080) and run the following command as root:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

then I modified the app.listen to listen to port 8080

```
app.listen(8080, function(){
console.log('listening.........................................');
});
```

with Thanks to tony & E_net4 for putting me into right direction

Comment: any idea how same would be for osx?

Comment: no sorry im not a mac person but look into this -> http://xeiam.com/port-forwarding-80-to-8080-using-ipfw-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I actually fixed it. It was `app.listen(80);` in my `server.js` which I modified into `app.listen(8080);` That's all...and it worked like a charm so no need to port forward in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps that helped me in similar error.

I stopped the service 'mongod' and express 'app.js' then I rebooted, started the service and app.js again. This solved for me.

Another thing I tried that solved this problem was opening config.js of mongo-express and changing the local port for it and set it to say 37017.